# Force the user to insert only number in the prompt

Tags: javascript

I am working on a guessing game. How can I force the user to put a number in the prompt box?

```
var secretNumber = 4
var guess = Number(prompt("Guess a Number"));
if (guess === secretNumber) {
    alert("you got it right brah!!!!!!");
}
if (NaN(guess)) {
    alert("must input numbers")
    return false;
}
else if (guess < secretNumber) {
    alert("your number is too low !");
}
else {
    alert("your number is too high !");
}





if (NaN(guess)) {
    alert("must input numbers")
    return false;
```

I expect when the user fill in letters or anything not numbers to get an alert telling him that he must use numbers.

Comment: If you're going to use a prompt you can only check after the user has submitted as all the prompt does is return the String value of the user input as a whole.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a `do-while` loop to keep prompting the user until they have entered a number:

```js
let inp;
do {
  inp = +prompt("Guess a number");
} while(isNaN(inp));

// --- Perform logic with `inp` as a number ---
// You can now assume inp here is a number
console.log(inp + 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var secretNumber = 4;
var guess;
while(true){
   while(isNaN(guess=prompt("Guess a Number")))alert("must input numbers");
   if (guess == secretNumber){
     alert("you got it right brah!!!!!!");
     break;
   }
   else if(guess < secretNumber)
     alert("your number is too low !");
   else 
     alert("your number is too high !")
}
```

if you instead wanted to notify them as they put in the text then that would be impossible.